# QUnit with setup and teardown for async ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

Can someone provide an example of doing a setup/teardown model for async tests ajax requests on qunit?

e.g.

setup: create database
t1: REST call to create document 1
t2: REST call to update document 1
t3: REST call to delete document 1
t4: REST call to update document 1 (error cause 1 has been deleted)
t5: REST call to create document 2
teardown: clear all documents, delete database

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[QUnit setup/teardown methods](http://api.qunitjs.com/module/) can also use [stop()](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/stop) and [start()](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/start).

On the other hand, to test clientside code, considering mocking the actual requests. As you tagged with jquery, you're probably using $.ajax and its siblings, so [jquery-mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax) should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

start() and stop() is marked as deprecated in QUnit 2.X.

Using module hooks with assert argument can avoid using those deprecated method.

```
QUnit.module("module", {
    beforeEach:function(assert){
        var done = assert.async();
        setTimeout(function(){ // silly example
            done();
        }, 5000);
    },
    afterEach:function(assert){
        // same as beforeEach
    }
});
QUnit.test( "test", function( assert ) {...});
```